# Open an Umbraco web site using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, umbraco

I have a website hosted using Umbraco and I want to explore the website in Visual Studio to make changes to it. I would like to open the Code that is already hosted. Is there anyways to get to it ?. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe?  You probably need to start by contacting your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the source code from the live hosting (assuming you have FTP access) and open it in Visual Studio to look at the files and make changes. Just open the folder with the files in that you downloaded as an existing website in Visual Studio and you'll be sorted.

However, it will depend on what you want to change. If you want to edit the actual page content, you'll need to do that via the CMS interface (as that's all stored in the database). If you want to edit the Templates, CSS, Javascript, XSLT Macros, Razor Scripts (if its running the latest version of Umbraco and is using Razor) etc, then you can edit all of those by logging into the CMS as an Administrator. Templates, CSS and Javascript can be edited from the "Settings" section of the CMS.  Macros and more advanced stuff like data types can be edited from the "Developers" section of the CMS.

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood is that your Umbraco application will have been deployed in it compiled state.

In this case, you can download it and then open it in VS using the "File > Open Existing Website" option.

This will give you the ability to alter files like the CSS, javascript, masterpages, xslt and usercontrols but it will not provide you with access the "inner workings" of the CMS since this will all be compiled.

It is *very* rare that you should need to change any of the core CMS code but if you wanted to look around as a learning exercise (highly recommended), then you can [download the source code from here](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/releases).

Also be aware that the version running your site will not necessarily be the version available for download. The last version of the webforms-based Umbraco is 4.7.1.1 however they have just release Version 5 which is based upon MVC3.

**Edit:**

Version 5 was shelved and is no longer available. 4.11.x was the last version to be made available before the core API was rewritten in PetaPoco in v6.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is just an IDE.  You can open any file in it (within reason).  I often drag files I want to work on into the visual studio window in order to open them.

Generating a project from the files is a different trick altogether and takes a lot more effort.

[Try this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1325555/1178921) for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Download the project template for Umbraco for visual studio 2010

goto tools -> Extension Manager  then search for umbraco mvc in online gallery.

after the installation of template, you will be able to create umbraco MVC projects.