# How to configure .sln Visual Studio Project file to be stored in the project folder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, project

I come from Visual Studio 2008, where the .sln file used to be stored in the project folder. Now I see it is stored in documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ProjectName\, which I don't like at all.

How can I store it automatically in the project folder? Without cutting and pasting it each time I open a new project...

Answer (score 5):

A screenshot with a Big Red Arrow on the relevant controls:

[image]

The "Create directory for solution" checkbox is ticked by default.  Turn it off to get the project stored in the same directory as the solution.  VS memorizes the last setting you used.

The "Location" property determines where the solution is stored.  The default is the path that you complain about.  Just edit it.  Or change the default setting like I did: Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, General, "Projects location" setting.

Comment: There aren't those controls if you do File->New Web Site :(

Comment: There is no project when you use that.  Read through the MSDN article to decide which approach suits you best: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can change the path where new projects and files are created by using the Options dialog box. Your existing projects remain in their current location.

1. On the Tools menu, select Options.
2. From the Projects and Solutions folder, select General.
3. In the Visual Studio projects location text box, enter a location for files and projects.

Comment: Uhm! Well, but it doesnt work! If I create a website project, it creates Website1\ with projects, and than Website1 (2) with .sln :O

Comment: you could try to uncheck the "Create directory for solution" checkbox when you save the .sln the first time.

Comment: Uhm, where is that option? I don't find it in "File->New WebSite"

Comment: Also because in fact it save sln automatically, I didn't save it :O

Comment: @markzzz You need to save it as a [project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1325588/147211)