# How do I import ASP.NET project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have to maintain an ASP.NET project developed by a previous colleague. I have visual studio 2010 installed now and this is my first ASP.NET project. 
I have been trying in vain to Import the last deployed version of the project 
from the location of server_name\inetpub\wwwroot But so far nothing works where it will import, build and run in debug mode. I looked in the computer of the previous developer for all the project source code files but could only find the .sln file.

I have tried simply adding an existing project. I have tried creating a solution and adding existing components by navigating to the .vbproj file. I have tried using the tool bar with File » Add » Existing project. I have tried the solution(s) recommended at this URL;

[Visual Studio: Create a web application from existing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325555/visual-studio-create-a-web-application-from-existing-code)

The only one that comes close is, the method of creating a blank solution with 
the same name, copying the relevant deployed folder from server_name\inetpub\wwwroot to the blank solutions location. Then in the copied folder delete the .sln file. Back in visual studio File » Add » Existing Web Site and navigate to the copied folder. This builds the project and all looks okay but when I click on debug I receive numerous messages of "Microsoft JScript runtime error: object doesn't support this property or method". How do I fix this please??

Comment: For your specific problem on the jscript error, we'll need the relevant lines of code.

Comment: You'll be getting those errors as a result of your project references getting out of whack since you created a new solution file and started from scratch. You need to add in the dependencies for that project if you are going to proceed this way. Though given you have a .sln and a .vbproj I have to wonder why you would?

Comment: @NotMe Thanks for response but there are dozens of lines highlighted by the jscript error.  Here is one example - self._tabIndex = opt.owner.get_tabs().length;

Comment: You'll have to go through each one and fix the project references.  The one you identified is likely due to Telerik RadControls.  So find that assembly and add a project reference to it.